# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0]

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.x

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

This is the error am getting when integrating Facebook SDK in my react native project in the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are two build.gradle files.

Place the following lines in 'app/build.gradle' instead of 'build.gradle': (in the dependencies section)

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
```